# Implementing game states using reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, reactive-banana

In my breakout implementation there are two main behaviors that describe the 
game's main state:

```
paddlePosition :: Behavior t Point
ballPosition :: Behavior t Point
```

Both are implemented in terms of `tickEvent :: Event t ()` which discretely
updates them.

The `gameOverEvent :: Event t ()` filters all tick events where the ball
position is below the screen.

I would like to replace `paddlePosition` by a new behavior as soon as there
is a `gameOverEvent`, leaving the paddle in place, in pseudo code:

```
newPaddlePosition = \t -> case gameOverEvent of
    [] -> paddlePosition t
    ((t',()) : _) -> paddlePosition t'
```

The first question is: How do I express `newPaddlePosition` using
reactive-banana?

The second is question is a bit more vague: What is a good way to organize the
whole program depending on if the game is over or not? There are other
considerations like: How to handle `ballPosition`, how to draw the game, and so
on.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for *dynamic event switching*, in particular the `switchB` combinator.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816012/performing-a-single-switch-in-reactive-banana).

Note that the pseudocode for your `newPaddlePosition` function does not make much sense: It says that when the `gameOverEvent` never occurs, then the new paddle position is equal to `paddlePosition`, otherwise it is constant and equal to the value of `paddlePosition` at the time that the event occurs. This is impossible to express in a causal FRP library. You probably mean something else.